# how to access the #document inside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plyr

I am using the plyr.io in the angularJS using the custome directive.

So it was created the iframe element and inside that create a #document

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/274993951?loop=false&amp;autoplay=false&amp;muted=false&amp;gesture=media&amp;playsinline=true&amp;byline=false&amp;portrait=false&amp;title=false&amp;speed=true&amp;transparent=false&amp;customControls=true" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; encrypted-media; accelerometer; gyroscope" title="Player for Welcome to Wheelhouse College - Managers" id="myIframe" data-ready="true" tabindex="-1">
#document
<html>......html content......</html>

</iframe>
```

how can I acess the html data inside the #document?

Here is the custome directive

```
(function (base) {
    'use strict';

    base.directive('plyrPlayer', ['logService', '$timeout', function (logService, $timeout) {
       return {
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
                var player;
                var element = $element[0];
                var secondsWatched = $attr.secondsWatched;
                var showMaximized = $attr.showMaximized === "on";
                var provider = $attr.plyrProvider;

               
                function createPlayer(vimeoId,videotype) {
                    
                    element.setAttribute('data-plyr-provider', videotype);
                    element.setAttribute('data-plyr-embed-id', vimeoId);
                    player = new Plyr(element, { "id": vimeoId, "autoplay": false, "hideControls": false, "clickToPlay": false });
                    
                    
                    player.on("play", function (data) {
                        
                        var loadingId = $element.data("loadingId");
                        if (angular.isNumber(loadingId)) {
                            logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: video loading failed assuming vimeoId: %o", loadingId);
                            $element.removeData("loadingId");
                            $element.data("vimeoId", loadingId);
                        } else
                            logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: play video vimeoId: %o", $element.data("vimeoId"));

                        function maximizePlayer(el) {
                            var style = el.style;
                            style.position = "fixed";
                            style.zIndex = "100";
                            style.top = "0";
                            style.bottom = "0";
                            style.left = "0";
                            style.right = "0";

                            var iframe = element.firstChild;
                            style = iframe.style;
                            // size to 100% of the viewport
                            style.width = "100vw";
                            style.height = "100vh";
                        }

                        if (angular.isFunction($scope.$parent.onPlayStart))
                            $scope.$parent.onPlayStart();

                        if (showMaximized)
                            maximizePlayer(element);
                    });

                 
                    player.on("pause", function (data) {
                        
                        const instance = data.detail.plyr;
                        var mydata = {
                            duration: instance.media.duration,
                            percent: Math.floor(instance.media.currentTime / instance.media.duration * 100),
                            seconds: instance.media.currentTime,
                            vimeoId: $element.data("vimeoId")
                        };

                        $scope.$parent[secondsWatched] = mydata;

                        if (angular.isFunction($scope.$parent.onPlayStop)) {
                            // $scope.$parent.onPlayStop(data.duration === data.seconds);
                            $scope.$parent.onPlayStop(false);
                        }

                    });

                    player.on("timeupdate", function (data) {
                                          
                        $timeout(function () {
                            const instance = data.detail.plyr;
                            var mydata = {
                                duration: instance.media.duration,
                                percent: Math.floor(instance.media.currentTime / instance.media.duration * 100),
                                seconds: instance.media.currentTime,
                                vimeoId: $element.data("vimeoId")
                            };

                            $scope.$parent[secondsWatched] = mydata;
                            $scope.$parent.$digest();
                            $scope[secondsWatched] = mydata;

                            if (angular.isFunction($scope.$parent.updateSecondsWatched))
                                $scope.$parent.updateSecondsWatched(mydata);

                        }, 10);

                    });


                    player.on("ended", function (data) {
                        
                        function minimizePlayer(el) {
                            var style = el.style;
                            // return the player to the original size
                            style.position = "";
                            style.zIndex = "";
                            style.top = "";
                            style.bottom = "";
                            style.left = "";
                            style.right = "";
                            var iframe = el.firstChild;

                            style = iframe.style;
                            style.width = "";
                            style.height = "";
                        }

                        logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: video ended vimeoId: %o", $element.data("vimeoId"));

                        $scope.$parent.onPlayStop(true);

                        if (showMaximized)
                            minimizePlayer(element);

                    });

                    player.on("loadstart", function (data) {
                        $element.removeData("loadingId");
                        $element.data("vimeoId", data.id);
                        logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: video loaded vimeoId: %o", data.id);

                    });

                    player.on("ready", function (data) {
                        const instance = data.detail.plyr;
                        var progress = 0;
                        if (angular.isFunction($scope.$parent.getCurrentProgress))
                            progress = $scope.$parent.getCurrentProgress();

                        if (progress <= 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        
                        data.detail.plyr.loop = false;
                        //player.embed.setCurrentTime(progress);
                        player.pause();
                    });

                    return player;
                }
                ;


                $scope.$watchGroup([$attr.plyrEmbedId, $attr.plyrProvider], function (value1,value2,scope) {
                    
                   
                    var videotype=scope.$$watchers[0].last;
                    if (videotype == "vimeo") {
                        var vimeoId = parseInt(scope.$$watchers[1].last);
                        if (!angular.isNumber(vimeoId)) {
                            logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: vimeoId is not available")
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        var vimeoId = scope.$$watchers[1].last;
                    }
                    if (!player) {

                        player = createPlayer(vimeoId,videotype);
                        logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: created player vimeoId: %o", vimeoId);
                        $element.data("vimeoId", vimeoId);
                    } else {

                        player.pause();
                            //.then(function () {
                            // loading the video often doesn't complete to the point that the loaded event is fired
                            // but the video is loaded.  Loading the thumbnail image fails.  Capture the loadingId and
                            // apply that in playing if it exists.

                            $element.data("loadingId", vimeoId);
                            logService.debug("evimeoPlayer: video loading vimeoId: %o", vimeoId);
                            player.captions["active"]= null
                              player.captions["currentTrack"] =-1

                        player.source = {
                            type: 'video',
                            sources: [
                                {
                                    src: vimeoId,
                                    provider: videotype,
                                },
                            ],
                        };
                         
                        $element.data("vimeoId", vimeoId);
                            //player.loadVideo(vimeoId).catch(function () {
                        //    $element.data("vimeoId", vimeoId);
                            //});
                        //})

                    }
                }, true);
            },
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: false
        }
    }
    ]
    );

}(lmsApp));
```

I didn't get the cross origin error as well in the browser and I have tried to access the content document using the following code `var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;` but it will getting the null.

edited code is

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
```

Comment: you can't if it's not same origin (technically you can in a way, but that requires co-operation from the other page - not sure vimeo would add the required code for you)